# How can I icrease the canvas of a transparent icon?

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-10.3-rio

I have some transparent icons smaller in size than the ImageList where I want to add them. I try to add them as usual with `ImageList.AddIcon(IcoHandle);` but it seems they are scaled to the ImageList size. I want find a way to increase the canvas of my Icon with transparent color so it will be added in the ImageList without scaling. Is this possible ?

Update1:

I've done as David said, but the icon lost transparency...

```
 LoadIconWithScaleDown(HInstance, PChar('NUT_VITAL'), ISmall, ISmall, hI);
 Ico.Handle:= hI;

 Bmp:= TBitmap.Create;
 Bmp.Transparent:= True;
 Bmp.PixelFormat:= pf32bit;
 Bmp.SetSize(ISize, ISize);
 Bmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Ico);
 Pics.Add(Bmp, nil);
 Bmp.Free;
```

Comment: Create a new image of the required size, and draw the smaller image onto it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan check my update...

Comment: Why are you creating a visual control (TImage) to copy the icon? That's totally inappropriate (and unnecessary).

Comment: @KenWhite how can i do otherwise ?

Comment: Create a `TBitmap` in code instead, and use it in place of the `TImage`. A `TImage` control is for visually displaying an image to a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out... thanks to David, Ken and Torbins answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732435/how-to-get-bitmap-transparancy-without-the-need-to-paint-first).

I had to set brush style to `bsClear` before setting the size of the bitmap. :)

```
LoadIconWithScaleDown(HInstance, PChar('NUT_VITAL'), ISmall, ISmall, hI);
Ico.Handle := hI;

Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
try
  Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Bmp.SetSize(ISize, ISize);
  N := (ISize - ISmall) div 2;
  Bmp.Canvas.Draw(N, N, Ico);
  Pics.Add(Bmp, nil);
finally
  Bmp.Free; 
end;
```

Comment: Weird. Why don't you pass ISize to LoadIconWithScaleDown

Comment: `ISize` is my image list size, but I want some icons to be samller than the usual size...

Comment: If you have the thing sitting in a resource, call LoadIconWithScaleDown as many times as you need to get it loaded at whichever size you need at that point in the code

Comment: Yes, but I use those icons for some TButton, and they work with a ImageList.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you doing both. What you makes you think you can only call LoadIconWithScaleDown once?

Comment: But I cannot load a image into a TButton, his image is set by `ImageIndex` property.

Comment: You can absolutely do this. But if you don't want to, fine.

Comment: David, I don't know how, other than setting the `ImageIndex`...

Comment: You load the icon at the desired size and the add it to the image list.